# Why don't nested sizers expand in wxPython if hidden at init?

Tags: wxpython, panel, init, sizer

I am trying to build a 3-panel GUI and everything was going great until I tried to nest panels/windows inside of other panels and hide them upon GUI startup.

See this image... The yellow/green/blue boxes were automatically expanded to fill up their panels during init, but the little purple box is built BUT then hidden during wx.Panel init until a 2 second timer expires and then at that time that object's Show() method is invoked.  At that time it does not not fill up the containing panel.  It seems that hiding a panel during init causes the panel sizer to pick the default size, 20x20.

[image: sizer test]

Here is the code:

```
import wx
import  wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class NavPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, parent, actionPanel):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent) #, size=(200,600))
        self.actionPanel = actionPanel
        self.SetBackgroundColour("Yellow")

class ActionPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, parent, target_item=None):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("Green")

        self.sc = NestedScrolledActionPanel(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.sc, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def show_child(self):
        # Putting a sizer here doesn't work either...
        self.sc.Show()


class NestedScrolledActionPanel(wx.ScrolledWindow):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, parent, target_item=None):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("Purple")

        # I don't want to show this at starutp, but hiding it causes the sizer to startup at 20x20!
        # Comment out this line and the sizer set in ActionPanel works, but you see it at startup
        self.Hide()       

class ConsolePanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel): 
    """"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""

        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("Blue")

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        mainSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        topSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(mainSplitter)

        self.rightPanel = ActionPanel(topSplitter)
        self.rightPanel.SetBackgroundColour("Green")

        leftPanel = NavPanel(topSplitter, self.rightPanel)
        leftPanel.SetBackgroundColour("Yellow")

        topSplitter.SplitVertically(leftPanel, self.rightPanel, sashPosition=0)
        topSplitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(200)

        bottomPanel = ConsolePanel(mainSplitter)

        mainSplitter.SplitHorizontally(topSplitter, bottomPanel, sashPosition=400)
        mainSplitter.SetSashGravity(1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(mainSplitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        return


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Sizer Test",
                          size=(800,600))

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(2000)

    def OnTimer(self, e):
        self.panel.rightPanel.show_child()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    print "Launching frame"
    frame = MainFrame()
    print "starting mainloop"
    app.MainLoop()
```

The reason why I want this panel hidden upon GUI startup is because I will have many different panels residing in that ActionPanel space (the green box) and when the user clicks on a tree node in the yellow box, the panel that is displayed in the green box will be hidden and a different panel will be shown.  If I don't hide all of the panels at startup, they are "stacked" on top of each other and I will have to set a timer to go through and hide them all at some point after GUI launches???  That seems hokey.  How else can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `self.Layout()` to your show_child method.  Just showing the child does not trigger a layout like a size event would.  For those times when layout needs to change without a size event you need to call Layout yourself.

Comment: Well, that worked for my small example here but not in my larger application.  I had to call 'self.Layout()' after 'self.sc.Show()', not before it.  Why would you not call 'self.sc.Layout()'?  I'm still very confused.  What are these methods doing under the hood?

Comment: Yes, more complex layouts can make things like this a little more tricky to figure out.  Using the WIT (http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget_Inspection_Tool) can really help diagnose layout troubles and how to work around them.  In general I've found that it usually works to call the Layout method of the window that owns the sizer that needs to be adjusted, although sometimes it is the parent's Layout that needs to be called.

Comment: Very cool.. bookmarking that.  Thanks for your help, again.  I finally broke through the wall in the larger app.  I'll answer my own question to detail that, but you get the check.

Answer (score 0):

I went through a lot of trouble to build a simple case for Stack Overflow, but that only exposed a second problem, which RobinDunn answered.  My other, more maddening problem was that I was trying to add two sizers to an object.  Only the last one got the sizer, the rest were 20x20 and I couldn't figure it out.

I wanted two different panels to share the same parent panel at different times, so I was doing this...  (untested code)..

```
some_object= wx.Panel(self)  # Could be anything
sizer = BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(some_object, 1, wx.EXPAND)
sizer.SetSizer(sizer)

something_else = wx.Panel(self)  # Could be anything
something_else.Hide()
sizer = BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(something_else, 1, wx.EXPAND)
sizer.SetSizer(sizer)
```

But what I should have done is this:

```
some_object= wx.Panel(self)  # Could be anything
something_else = wx.Panel(self)  # Could be anything
something_else.Hide()
sizer = BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(some_object, 1, wx.EXPAND)
sizer.Add(something_else, 1, wx.EXPAND)
sizer.SetSizer(sizer)
```

Then of course, do the Layout() thing after each show/hide of the different panels, and 36 hours of head-bashing later, I'm cured!